# For loop through all elements of vector of ones

Tags: matlab, for-loop

In Matlab, say that I have a 3x1 vector of ones. Then I want to do a for loop, changing one element to a zero. So that I get `(0,1,1)`, `(1,0,1)` and `(1,1,0)` from my loop. How can I go about this?

I have tried

```
for i = s
    i = 0;
    print(s);
end
```

where s is my vector, but it doesn't work. Note that I'm a beginner at programming.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of showing what's wrong with your code, I'll show you a more Matlab-like way to do it:

```
n = 3; %// problem size
matrix = ones(n)-eye(n); %// n x n matrix with all ones except zeros at the diagonal
for k = 1:n %// pick each row
    disp(mat2str(matrix(k,:))) %// create a string from n-th row and display it
end
```

Result:

```
[0 1 1]
[1 0 1]
[1 1 0]
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that I can implement that idea into my program.

Comment: If this is part of a program you probably need the vectors `[0 1 1]`, `[1 0 1]`  etc, not their string representation. So just use `matrix(k,:))` within the `for` loop